# JBoss 7 HSQLDB XA Datasource

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, hsqldb

I want to use a HSQLDB datasource with JBoss 7.
But I also want to use the datasource in XA mode.
As far as I know, HSQLDB supports XA-transactions since 2.2.0 and I am using the latest version of HSQLDB. I also found the corresponding class file in the HSQLDB jar: org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnection.

But on startup I get the following exception from JBoss:

```
Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:461)
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:398)
 at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:781)
 at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:344)
 at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
 at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
 at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
 at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
 at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
 at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDatabaseType(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:636) [camunda-engine-7.0.0-Final.jar:]
 at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDataSource(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:598) [camunda-engine-7.0.0-Final.jar:]
 at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.init(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:385) [camunda-engine-7.0.0-Final.jar:]
 at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.JtaProcessEngineConfiguration.init(JtaProcessEngineConfiguration.java:54) [camunda-engine-7.0.0-Final.jar:]
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.config.ManagedJtaProcessEngineConfiguration.init(ManagedJtaProcessEngineConfiguration.java:34)
 at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:357) [camunda-engine-7.0.0-Final.jar:]
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController.startProcessEngine(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:178)
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController$2.run(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:132)
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController$2.run(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:130)
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.util.Tccl.runWithTccl(Tccl.java:53)
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.util.Tccl.runUnderClassloader(Tccl.java:45)
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController.startInternal(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:130)
 at org.camunda.bpm.container.impl.jboss.service.MscManagedProcessEngineController$1.run(MscManagedProcessEngineController.java:91)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_07]
 at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not find accessor on XADataSource: 
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:603)
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:444)
 ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Method setURL not found
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.util.Injection.inject(Injection.java:141)
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.util.Injection.inject(Injection.java:70)
 at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:578)
 ... 30 more
```

Here is my datasource configuration:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/LiferayDS" pool-name="LiferayDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
        jdbc:hsqldb:file:../../hsql-data/LiferayDS
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>hsqldb</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
        <interleaving>false</interleaving>
        <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
        <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password></password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</xa-datasource>
```

It looks like the XA class from HSQLDB doesn't provide the common XA configuration interface.
How must I configure the datasource to be able to use HSQLDB in transaction mode?

Comment: Are you sure that HSQLDB supports XA transactions?  https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/NonXaDataSource suggests otherwise.

Comment: According to http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#N100CF, HSQLDB does seem to support XA transactions.  Will try to find examples in the documentation.

Comment: https://fossies.org/dox/hsqldb-2.3.4/classorg_1_1hsqldb_1_1jdbc_1_1pool_1_1JDBCXADataSource.html is almost certain proof that HSQLDB 2.3.4 supports XA transactions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find class `org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXADataSource` in http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/apidocs/org/hsqldb/jdbc/package-summary.html.

Comment: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/apidocs/index.html?org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDataSourceFactory.html does refer to `JDBCXADataSource`, which may be an internal class.

Comment: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool/wiki/Atomikos-TransactionsEssentials-Configuration shows an example of the configuration of an XA data source that uses HSQLDB class `JDBCXADataSource`.

Comment: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/c52cd8962ad5238c4ac0472a495b83e8d3bb956c/core/src/test/resources/META-INF/jta-hsqldb.properties configures a `JDBCXADataSource` for Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the correct configuration for a HSQLDB xa-datasource

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/LiferayDS" pool-name="LiferayDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <xa-datasource-property name="Url">
        jdbc:hsqldb:file:../../hsql-data/LiferayDS
    </xa-datasource-property>
    <driver>hsqldb</driver>
    <xa-pool>
        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
        <interleaving>false</interleaving>
        <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
        <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
    </xa-pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password></password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</xa-datasource>
```